# C++ - Assignment of raw pointers to unique_ptr nodes in a Linked List

Tags: c++, pointers, types, linked-list, nodes

I'm trying to figure out how to update my tail raw pointer to a new tail after removing a node in my linked list. (is homework)

I've defined the head and tail as

```
    std::unique_ptr<Node> head ;
    Node* tail ;
```

and in my function for removing a node from the back I have the following implementation.

```
int Deque::remove_back(){
if (empty()) {throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Empty"));};

std::unique_ptr<Node> old;

Node* p = head.get();

int return_value = tail->val;

while (p->next != tail)
{p = p->next)}

old = move(tail);
tail = p;

return return_value;
}
```

So tail is a raw pointer of type Node.
P is a raw pointer of type Node.

Head is a unique pointer of type Node.

I'm setting p = head.get()

so now p points to the head

p = p->next should be iterating down my nodes.

The problem is that `p->next != tail`

p->next is a pointer to the next node following whatever p is.

I'm trying to set a pointer to a node to be equal to a raw pointer of type node (tail).

Its telling me I can't do this.

I believe its due to p->next not changing into an owning pointer instead of the observing one I declared it to be.

Errors:

```
Deque.cpp|68|error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'std::unique_ptr<Node>' and 'Node*')|

Deque.cpp|69|error: cannot convert 'std::unique_ptr<Node>' to 'Node*' in assignment|

Deque.cpp|71|error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::unique_ptr<Node>' and 'std::remove_reference<Node*&>::type {aka Node*}')|
```

Comment: Are you requied to use `tail`? It does not help at all.

Comment: Yea unfortunately. :(

Comment: a `tail` in a single-linked list is only useful for fast inserts at the end of the list, but is otherwise useless since you can't use it for fast removals at the end of the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error messages imply that `Node::next` is a `std::unique_ptr<Node>`.  You cannot compare/assign a `std::unique_ptr` directly to a raw pointer.  You need to use the `std::unique_ptr::get()` method instead:

```
while (p->next.get() != tail) {
    p = p->next.get();
}
```

Also, your loop is not taking into account when the list has only 1 node in it (`head == tail`). `p->next` will be `nullptr` on the second iteration and crash.  And since you would be removing the last node in the list, you would need to reset `head` to `nullptr`.  Either way, when assigning `p` as the new `tail`, you need to reset `p->next` to `nullptr` so it will no longer be pointing at the old node.

Try this:

```
int Deque::remove_back(){
    if (empty()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Empty");
    }

    int return_value = tail->val;

    if (!head->next) {
        head = nullptr; // or: head.reset();
        tail = nullptr;
    }
    else {
        Node* p = head.get();
        Node *prev = p;
        while (p->next->next) {
            p = p->next.get();
            prev = p;
        }
        tail = prev;
        tail->next = nullptr; // or: tail->next.reset();
    }

    return return_value;
}
```

That being said, it can be tricky using `std::unique_ptr` in a linked-list implementation.  If you want automatic destruction of nodes, you could just use raw pointers and wrap the list inside of a class that destroys the nodes when itself is destroyed, and then `remove_back()` can destroy the node being removed.

The STL already has such classes available: `std::list` (double linked) and `std::forward_list` (single linked).  You should be using them instead of a manual list implementation.

Comment: Its for homework and as such there's a lot of restrictions to make me consider the why's and hows of implementation for using smart pointers.

Comment: "you are not resetting p->next to nullptr" It will be fixed when OP will realize that he cannot assign raw pointer to `std::unique_ptr`. I think it makes sense to use `std::unique_ptr` if used properly.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<Node> old;` and `Node* Tail` can't be moved into one another. If I get() tail then it should work.

Comment: @Slava: a `std::unique_ptr` can be reset to nullptr using the `reset()` method or `operator=`. However, a proper use of smart pointers in a linked-list implementation would be to use `std::shared_ptr` instead of `std::unique_ptr` for the individual nodes, and then make `tail` and `p` be `std::weak_ptr` instead of raw pointers.

Comment: @RemyLebeau it will work just fine with `std::unique_ptr` and raw pointer or experimental `observer_ptr`, just logic need to be fixed

Comment: If I could use share_ptr's this homework problem would be muuuuch simpler for me. 

I'm trying to use the operator= method. `tail = p;` and then `p->next=nullptr;` did the trick I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You function has issue when there is only one element. You need a condition (with code duplicate) or make it little bit more complicated:

```
int Deque::remove_back(){
    if (empty()) {throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Empty"));};

    Node *newtail = nullptr;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> *curr = &head;
    while( curr->get() != tail ) {
        newtail = curr->get();
        curr = &(*curr)->next;
    }

    tail = newtail;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> tmp = std::move( *curr );

    return tmp->val;
}
```

Comment: I like your loop better than mine.